# Glassfish JDBC Connection Pool: don't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, glassfish

This is very strange behavior of Glassfish server. Trying to connect to MySQL from the server admin console is unsuccessful, BUT... After I run WorkBench and connect to the database (no problem), Glassfish's ping works fine, and after that there are no problems connecting the server to the database. Moreover, I can close WorkBench or leave it active - this no longer matters until the MySQL service is restarted. And i (trough admin's server panel), and my App connect to DB without any problem. I checked everything in the GlassFish Connection poll settings 100 times.

Only the MySQL settings remain, but my.ini contains three lines,

```
    [mysqld]
    basedir=c:/mysql
    datadir=F:/mysql/data
    secure-file-priv = F:/MYSQL/INOUT
```

in addition, when using the TomCat server (in the application), no problems arise. I run Windows OS and MySQL separately as a service from the console if necessary, that is, the server does not start in the system by default. The error itself in the Glassfish server administrator console is uninformative - three connection attempts - unsuccessful)

Now I’m studying Glassfish, and I can’t just forget this nightmare, I have to constantly launch WorkBench before connecting to the server. But I'm terribly tired of it. I can't find anything like this anywhere on the web. What's the problem? Logic fails)